# Convert an array of dates into a date range

Tags: php

I have an array of dates: from and to 's.
i.e:

```
array(
    [0] => array('from' => '19-01-2000' 'to' => '20-01-2000')
    [1] => array('from' => '20-01-2000' 'to' => '21-01-2000')
    [2] => array('from' => '21-01-2000' 'to' => '22-01-2000')
    [3] => array('from' => '23-01-2000' 'to' => '24-01-2000')
    [4] => array('from' => '24-01-2000' 'to' => '25-01-2000')
)
```

I am trying to find a way to convert create a new array which will only have the date ranges, 
i.e:

```
array(
    [0] => array('from' => '19-01-2000' 'to' => '22-01-2000')
    [1] => array('from' => '23-01-2000' 'to' => '25-01-2000')
)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: sorry, but how is the output array calculated exactly?

Comment: as the date ranges from the input array. :-)

Comment: yes, I get this part :D But I don't see the relation between them?!

Comment: entry 0 to date is equal to entry 1 from date :-) for example.

Comment: Is the input always sorted, and are they always one day long?

Comment: yes the input is always sorted and always one day long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved it in the following way.

```
    $new_array = array();
    $j = 0;
    $i = 0;
    $flag = true;
    $range = false;
    while ($flag) {
        if ($array[$j+1] == null) {
            $flag = false;
        }
        if ($array[$j]['date_to'] == $array[$j+1]['date_from']) {
            if (!$range) {
                $new_array[$i] = $array[$j];
                $j++;
                $range = true;
            }
            else {
                $j++;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (!$range) {
                $new_array[$i] = $array[$j];
            }
            else {
                $new_array[$i]['date_to'] = $array[$j]['date_to'];
                $range = false; 
            }
            $i++;
            $j++;
        }
    }
```

$new_array now contains only the date ranges.